# Product collection by category id, gives zero products

Tags: magento2, collection, category-products

The following code, returns an empty collection in most categories, even if the category indeed has products:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Is it working for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
) {
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

put below code in your method

```
$categoryId = 'yourcategoryid';
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    return $collection;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below codes it's working on my end.

```
$categoryId = 21; // YOUR CATEGORY ID
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');


$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
    //print_r($product->getData());
    // printing category name and url
    echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}
```

Please used the Dependency Injection method instead of Object manager.
Reference link : http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-all-products-of-a-category/

Comment: your code seems correct, but it's not working on my side

Comment: Any error message or you have set valid category ?

Comment: Yes category is valid. There's no error, just returning empty collection

Comment: Please check product options likes enable, in stock, Proper categories assign. Also do the indexing process so search product available in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below ways :

**EDIT 1 :**

```
$categoryID = '2';
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $categoryID]);
```

---

**EDIT 2 :**

```
$categoryId = '2';
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->load($categoryId);
$collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->load($categoryId);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
return $collection;
```